# How can I get an object from Amazon S3 using C# where the key name is set as a variable

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a problem whereby I am trying to get an object from Amazon S3 using C#.

If I pass the key as a hardcoded string the get is successful. However, if I assign the same string to a variable and pass that variable into the get object request I get a `The specified key does not exist` response.

Specifically the following snippet results in a successful get request

```
var getRequest = new Amazon.S3.Model.GetObjectRequest
{
    BucketName = BucketName,
    Key = "foo/bar/test.dat"
};
```

whereas the following snippet results in the `The specified key does not exist`

```
keyName = "foo/bar/test.dat";
var getRequest = new Amazon.S3.Model.GetObjectRequest
{
    BucketName = BucketName,
    Key = keyName
};
```

How can I get the object using a variable as the object name is not fixed so I cannot progress with the first snippet?

Comment: Did you modify keyName after creating the GetObjectRequest, but before calling GetObject?

Comment: thanks @jarmod. No - the keyName variable is set before the GetObjectRequest is created and is not subsequently modified

Comment: Can you print the Key of the getRequest object just before calling GetObject to verify? If it’s what you expected then the object doesn’t actually exist at the time of the request would be the most obvious explanation.

Comment: The print of the key just before calling GetObject verified it is the expected string and can confirm the object exists on s3 (both by verifying via AWS console and by hard coding the Key inside the request (first snippet in my question)

Comment: Is the key actually `foo/bar/test.dat` or does it have any unusual characters in it?

Comment: No special or unusual characters @jarmod. To verify I navigated to the object in s3 and copied the key name from the console and pasted into my code so is exactly as expected. I’m at a loss a snippet one works fine but snippet two (which is all but identical) doesn’t work

Comment: Can you share any more of your code, how are you building your s3 client and consuming the `getRequest`?  And is this running on Windows or Linux.  And can you repro locally and up in AWS (ec2 or fargate)